# browser chrome always prompt "your computer is infected..."

Tags: javascript, browser, malware, virus

My browser(chrome *Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)*) always prompt this js like dialog window when I open a new url(most of the time). I've tried to use **adware cleaner** and **anti-malware** by Malwarebytes to clean this, but it didn't work. Has someone encountered similar malware or ads? I've also tried Hijackthis to analysis my browser's entry, nothing suspicious found. Reset chrome won't work.[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNADd.png)

The title of that dialog window will show different if you open different website(if I open stackoverflow.com it will show stackoverflow.com says...).

Comment: Sounds like someone's spamming alerts

Comment: This question is not about programming, and is therefore not fit for StackOverflow. There might be other sites on StackExchange where you might ask for help, but not here.

Comment: Your DNS or Router or something else in the network might be infected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a question suited for StackOverflow, however, I will answer as it seems you have an issue with malware:

It sounds as if you are probably using the **Infinity New Tab** extension.

For users of **Infinity New Tab** - the Developer's Google account was compromised, and an update was released on 26-05-2017 with some malware included.

This malware randomly shows a browser popup claiming "Your computer is infected. You have to check it with antivirus".

I had this issue, and none of the different Anti-Virus utilities on several PCs detected any malware.

Background information can be found [here on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/6dluxp/your_computer_is_infected_you_have_to_check_it/) and a short notice [here from the Developer](http://infinitynewtab.com/notice.html).

You should remove that extension from Chrome; it has been removed from the Chrome Store while a replacement version is verified by Google.